# IPA Server installation failure due to port 8443 issue

Tags: linux, ipa, administration

I'm trying to install ipa-server on centos 7 and i'm getting below error

```
IPA requires port 8443 for PKI but it is currently in use.
ipa.ipapython.install.cli.install_tool(Server): ERROR    Aborting installation
ipa.ipapython.install.cli.install_tool(Server): ERROR    The ipa-server-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more information
```

This port is being used by httpd

```
semanage port -l | grep -w http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
[root@ipa ~]# ipa-server-install --setup-dns
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this conflict.

Comment: This question is really more for ServerFault. Also, your `semanage` command is not showing what's currently using port 8443.  It's only showing what SELinux will allow to use those ports..

Comment: i tried to get the port usage through below command
netstat -nlp|grep 8443
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      28510/httpd

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue as well, just turn off httpd before installing ipa-server. Worked for me. Thanks